# apache virtual host : how to add 2 virtual hosts?

Tags: apache-http-server

I am running my apache on windows for devlopment purposes.
My goal is to have 2 local websites configured:
I did that in my httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sites\site1
    ServerName site1.localhost
    <Directory C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\sites\site1>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

That works fine.
Now I would like to add site2 as well. 
If I add site2, I still go to site1 `(*:80)`

I tried to change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<site1.localhost*:80>`
No success.

I want to keep the same port (80) for all my websites. 
I tried with alias: problem is the document root points to apache installation and hence links like /css.css gives 404 errors

Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I would like to add site2 as well

You need something like the following.

In `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/Proxymis/Desktop/sites/site1
    ServerName site1
    ServerAlias *.site1
    <Directory C:/Users/Proxymis/Desktop/sites/site1>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/Users/Proxymis/Desktop/sites/site2
    ServerName site2
    ServerAlias *.site2
    <Directory C:/Users/Proxymis/Desktop/sites/site2>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Notes:

- I've added `ServerAlias` lines above
- Paths are normally written with `/` instead of `\`
- The virtual hosts should be defined in `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` not `conf\httpd.conf`
- `conf\httpd.conf` should contain `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

In `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       site1
127.0.0.1       site2
::1             site1
::1             site2
```